# How to automatically wrap ASP.NET action result in JSON (and async)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, async-await

We use the following code to automatically wrap action results that *do not derive* from `ActionResult` into JSON.

```
// auto json wrapper
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var return_type = ((ReflectedActionDescriptor)filterContext.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.ReturnType;

    // check if the return type is an ActionResult
    if (!typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(return_type))
    {
        // capture the result from the action
        var result = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.Execute(filterContext, filterContext.ActionParameters);
        // set the result, this means that the rest of the normal path will not be executed
        filterContext.Result = Json(result);
        // manually call OnActionExecuted
        this.OnActionExecuted(new ActionExecutedContext(ControllerContext, filterContext.ActionDescriptor, false, null));
    }
}
```

This means that we can quite easily use composition for returning json to our web app:

```
// returns json with the overview, including a list of LolCats
public object Overview()
{
    return new { name = "LolCats", list = ListLolCats() }
}

// returns a json array with lolcats
public IEnumerable<object> ListLolCats()
{
    foreach ( var cat in Db.LolCats )
        yield return new { type = cat.type };
}
```

Problem is that we want to move more to the async mvc pattern, and of course this won't work because our autowrapper in the OnActionExecuting method is a synchronous method.

Is there any way to have a json autowrapper like above, but one that will work with async actions?

Comment: Would creating your own custom ActionResult be a viable option? You would have to be explicit in your return types of your controller actions if you did that though so I assume not

Comment: What version of .NET and MVC are you using? I'd be surprised if there isn't an `OnActionExecutingAsync` in everything after 4.0.

Comment: @krillgar - Looks like you're right... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecutingasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: That's for a filter. I don't see anything for my controller, but then again I'm using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: I'll have go! Will investigate further with a newer mvc version and will post it here! Thanks already

Comment: Why not use WebApi controller if you always want to return JSON?